# TextArea value not showing any new lines breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The .val() of a textarea doesn't take new lines into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481025/the-val-of-a-textarea-doesnt-take-new-lines-into-account)

I have a text area when i type a message in the text area with newlines and get the value back from the text area the newlines are not preserved and the text is written as one line. how do i get the newlines from the text area?I am using IE 9 and Mozilla, Opera, Safari

```
var message = $(".chatpaneltext textarea").attr("value");
```

Comment: What language? PHP? Something else?

Comment: Could we see the code please?

Comment: How are you determining that there are no line break in the data? At the moment you are just loading it into a variable.

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481025/the-val-of-a-textarea-doesnt-take-new-lines-into-account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481025/the-val-of-a-textarea-doesnt-take-new-lines-into-account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are intepreting your line breaks `\r\n` as `<br />` tags.

```
text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
```

If you're using `PHP` there is the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function. Or any other language, the above regex should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert new lines to html 
 tags with `nl2br()` function before outputting.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using PHP to process the input from your textarea, you can use the `nl2br()` function to convert newline characters to `<br/>`. You can also accomplish this in javascript using `string.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');`.