# htmlEncode and htmlDecode is eliminating spaces and line breaks <br>? Any alternative available?

Tags: javascript, jquery

our web application shares code. To share the proper code we have used htmlEncode and htmlDecode as follow so that all the htmlTags are handled properly when they pass via http protocol as follows

```
     htmlEncode = function (value) {
     if (value) {
         return $('<div />').text(value).html();
     }
     else {
         return '';
     }
 },
htmlDecode = function (value) {
    if (value) {
        return $('<div />').html(value).text();
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
},
```

Now if user gave more spaces within the code, it gets coverted to single space (which ofcourse is not a big issue).

But the issue with this kind of implementation is if user has clicked **EnterKey** twice or thrice within the code sharing section, then its not taken as it is but the output is in a single line as follows:

**UserInput**: 
[image]

**Actual Output** 
[image]

**Expected Output** 
[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Is this output in a textbox/textarea? I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381331/jquery-convert-br-and-br-and-p-and-such-to-new-line) will help you.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482991/textarea-value-not-showing-any-new-lines-breaks?rq=1 - it might help with the specific problem of line breaks/new lines.

Comment: @F4R-20: User input is in a textarea,but the output is in a div

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected as this is exactly the effect peforming .text() on your value should have. I think you shouldn't use .text in this case