# How to keep text \r\n formatting on a textarea when you pull the text via javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting, textarea

Long story short, I have a textarea and I want to preserve the formatting with the proper line breaks. I'm getting the value of the text area with the following javascript call.

```
var letterText = document.getElementById("cnl-lettertext").value;
```

After that I sent it through an Ajax call and rest api to be saved to a database. I can't seem to get it to keep the \r\n characters or line breaks in the variable for some reason when I'm setting it.

I've tried setting white-space: pre on my css for it but that doesn't seem to work. I also don't want to just use .replace because that disrupts other functions.

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url, //url is built dynamically for a rest api.
    timeout : 5000,
    dataType : "json",
    statusCode : {  },
    success : function(data) {
                            
    
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your Ajax call. I'm guessing you're not encoding the value (with `encodeURIComponent(letterText)` for example), but hard to tell without seeing the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574876/line-breaks-not-working-in-textarea-output

Comment: @blex I went ahead and added my ajax call.

Comment: _"url is built dynamically for a rest api."_ <---- i think your problem might be right here. Try doing `'https://...' + encodeURIComponent(letterText) + '...'`

Comment: Fantastic @blex . That worked like a charm!

Comment: OK, then I posted an answer to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a request to a URL with line breaks, the browser will remove those line breaks, which are not URL-compatible. They need to be encoded.

You could do it manually with `encodeURIComponent`, but since you're using jQuery, take advantage of it, and pass query parameters the right way, with the `data` option. They will be encoded correctly by jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.example.com/endpoint', // don't add query params here
    timeout : 5000,
    dataType : "json",
    data: { // Add them here, they will be encoded automatically
      letterText: letterText,
      // ...
    },
    statusCode : {  },
    success : function(data) {}
});
```