# How to replace \n new line character in string so that <p> tag can show new line

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In a react application I am working on there is a condition that:

when a string has a new line character the

`<p>{string}</p>` tag in which string is to be displayed should be replaced with HTML new line character.

But of course this does not work.

Things I have already tried but did not work for me:

`const string = Hello\nHii`

1. `<p>{string.replace('\n', <br />)}</p>`

output:

`Hello<br />Hii`

2. `<p>{string.replace('\n', &amp;)}</p>`

output:

`Hello Hii`

I found the above suggestions in the following answers:

[the val of a textarea doesnt take new lines into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481025/the-val-of-a-textarea-doesnt-take-new-lines-into-account)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but have you tried splitting the string around `\n`, and then generating a new `<p>{string}</p>` for each element of the resulting split?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Using `pre` tag or css property `white-space: pre`:

   `<p><pre>{string}</pre></p>`
2. Using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

   `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: string.replace('\n', '<br />')}}></p>`